# Python, MyPy: how can I do an "exclusive OR" of types in a generic's restrictions?

Tags: python, generics, mypy

I want to use generics so that I can avoid the "invariant Xyz" problem, and have a single source of truth for a couple of large type structure implementations, without having to Union the internals of a generic class and the externals as well. My code has a heavily nested series of aliases for a custom data structure, which is basically a big JSON of dicts and lists where the "leaves" are of one of two possible types (call them `A` and `B`), and only ever "`A` exclusively", or "`B` exclusively" for a given tree. However, some substructures of the overall data model (like `List[A]` or `List[B]`) can happen in different layers of the dictionary tree, and I don't want to have a to maintain a specific type for each layer, when their logic is exactly the same.

I'll be using the invariant `List` as an example. I want to have an alias `C = List[A | B]` recognize `List[A]` and `List[B]` as valid subtypes, without having to do `C = List[A] | List[B]` everywhere this happens, since Unions would need discrimination to function properly in my utility functions. I want `A` and `B` to be replaced by a `GenericAorB` when I can, to auto-infer if I have a `List[A]` or `List[B]` in my utilities.

I took inspiration from here, since it seemed like what I needed:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-value-restriction

However it doesn't seem to work.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, List

GenericStringOrFloat = TypeVar("GenericStringOrFloat", str, float)
ListStringOrFloat    = List[GenericStringOrFloat]
my_list : ListStringOrFloat
my_list = [12.0, 13.0]       # Fine
my_list = ["hello", "world"] # Fine
my_list = ["hello", 13.0]    # Also fine... what ? shouldn't mypy return an error for this ?
```

I don't understand why the last line doesn't return an error. To me it looks like

```py
GenericStringOrFloat = TypeVar("GenericStringOrFloat", str, float)
```

is synonymous to

```py
GenericStringOrFloat = TypeVar("GenericStringOrFloat", str | float)
```

which is thus completely pointless. Is this maybe a MyPy bug ? the documentation looks like this syntax is precisely meant to avoid this issue, and have the generic not be a dumb Union.

I want an *exclusive OR*, not inclusive, between the types given to my generic type restrictions. Phrased mathematically (though not rigorously), I want a sort of functor which can do something like `ListUnionMapper : (A | B) -> List[A] | List[B]` (and for Dicts as well).

Any idea how to do that ?

=========

**EDIT:**

After some more experimentation, I found an almost workable solution, but it's still far from perfect. The TLDR is that you need to give the generic variable a second time to allow mypy to do the automatic inference/discrimination; but there is still a bunch of weirdness with generic type restrictions.

When declaring a variable, give it the specific type being used (ie, `str` or `float`), and when declaring a function signature, give it the generic type variable.

The below code exemplifies what I mean by this.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, List

GenericStringOrFloat  = TypeVar("GenericStringOrFloat", str, float)
ListFloat             = List[float]
ListString            = List[str]
ListStringOrFloat     = List[GenericStringOrFloat]
ListStringOrListFloat = ListString | ListFloat
my_list1A : ListStringOrFloat[      float] = [12.0,    13.0   ]  # Good as expected
my_list1B : ListStringOrFloat[      float] = ["hello", "world"]  # Error as expected: not float
my_list2A : ListStringOrFloat[str        ] = ["hello", "world"]  # Good as expected
my_list2B : ListStringOrFloat[str        ] = [12.0,    13.0   ]  # Error as expected: not str
my_list3  : ListStringOrFloat[str | float] = ["hello", 13.0   ]  # Good as expected
my_list4A : ListStringOrListFloat          = ["hello", "world"]  # Good as expected
my_list4B : ListStringOrListFloat          = [12.0,    13.0   ]  # Good as expected
my_list4C : ListStringOrListFloat          = ["hello", 13.0   ]  # Error as expected: not List[str] or List[float]
my_list4B                                  = ["hello", "world"]  # NB: doesn't infer/discriminate between List[str] and List[float], since union, so can be reassigned
my_list5A  : ListStringOrFloat[int]        = ["hello", 13.0   ]  # Error as expected: neither List[str} nor List[float]
my_list5B  : ListStringOrFloat[int]        = [1,       2      ]  # UNEXPECTED GOOD: this means that the type restriction basically doesn't work...

my_list_extra : ListStringOrFloat[GenericStringOrFloat] = ["hello", "world"]  # Error: Type variable GenericStringOrFloat is unbound


def return_first_element(lst: ListStringOrFloat[GenericStringOrFloat]) -> GenericStringOrFloat:
    assert len(lst) > 0
    return lst[0]


my_float_A : float = return_first_element(my_list1A)  # Good as expected
my_float_B : str   = return_first_element(my_list1A)  # Error: correctly infers that the function's return type is float
my_str_A   : float = return_first_element(my_list2A)  # Error: correctly infers that the function's return type is str
my_str_B   : str   = return_first_element(my_list2A)  # Good as expected
my_int_A   : float = return_first_element(my_list5B)  # Error: expects List[float] (and not List[Generic_Value]...)
my_int_B   : str   = return_first_element(my_list5B)  # Error: expression has type float + expects List[float] (and not List[Generic_Value]...)
my_int_C   : int   = return_first_element(my_list5B)  # Error: expression has type float + expects List[float] (and not List[Generic_Value]...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the `TypeVar`, but how mypy interprets `my_list : ListStringOrFloat`. Since it has no element type specified, it uses `object`. For example, your code also passes with `ListStringOrFloat[object]`, though I agree that appears to contradict the meaning of `GenericStringOrFloat`. Generally speaking, solitary `TypeVar`s don't really make sense, so I'm not too surprised it does something weird.

If you're only working with `List[A] | List[B]`, you could alias `ListX = List[A] | List[B]` then use `ListX[str, float]`, which does raise an error for `["hello", 13.0]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me a couple more ideas for experimentation, which I added in an edit. However, looking at `my_list5B` above, it looks like I'm not out of the woods yet. The reason I don't want to use `List[A] | List[B]` is because it would imply either no type inference or a massive overloading nightmare in my utilities, or just a LOT of non-DRY, almost duplicate code, which is a lot harder to maintain.